# How do I make sure a function will be called before another in a deeply modularized Backbone, Require.js and D3 app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, d3.js, requirejs, amd

Here is my headache. I'm developing a modularized javascript app and everything seems pretty neat except for one detail: I just can figure out how to load my `initialize` function only after my models have been fetched from the server with this `Backbone.collection.fetch()` method.

Please have a look into [this](https://github.com/n370/santafe_datavis/blob/8c12808a3640f68782c95d5d0663c1e0e9c1c180/client/scripts/views/map-view.js) file and possibly the [whole project](https://github.com/n370/santafe_datavis/) if you will, I appreciate a lot your collaboration.

Comment: I didn't look at those files because I *think* I had the same thought earlier. Let me know if the answer makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` has a success callback, as Reed Spool pointed out. Here's how you could use it:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
      // Preserve *this* in closures
      var that = this;

      this.collection.fetch({
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);            
          that.render();
      },
        error: function(){
          console.log('error');
        }
      });

    },

    render: function() {
      //render whatever you need from your fetched collection
    }      

});
```

Comment: Wonderful @cs_stackX ! I was sure it was something easilly manageable once you've untied the function scope enigma. Although rellying on a common-sense but sometimes questionable "that" hack, by calling `fetch` from inside of that view instance I instantly got what I wanted. Thanks for this absolutely ellegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm hearin you right, I think you need to use a "Success" callback function in fetch. See here #2 http://chilipepperdesign.com/2013/01/15/backbone-js-bind-callback-to-successful-model-fetch/

If it's decoupling function timing in modularized code you're worried about, as your question's header suggests, I suggest using Backbone's Events. See the Event Aggregator, or Pub-Sub design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to get around this using Backbone, is to use events. I've based this off the various blog posts of [MarionetteJS](http://marionettejs.com/) founder Derek Bailey, so I'll add references when I find the relevant ones later...

Your view would do this:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    _actuallyInitialize: function () {
        ...
    }
    initialize: function (attr, options) {
        ...
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'data:fetched', this._actuallyInitialize);
        ...
    }
});
```

And the code that is fetching your model, would do this:

```
var jqXHR = model.fetch();
jqXHR.done((function (bindModel) {
    return function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        ...
        bindModel.trigger('data:fetched');
    };
}(model)));
```

This way, you maintain the high-level modular approach, decouple the code (any number of views can update themselves on `fetch` now), and maintain readability. Your `Model` does stuff to itself, and your `View` does stuff to itself. Pretty neat, in my opinion, and one of the patterns I love using in Backbone. Thanks for the Q.

Comment: Looking back here and this answer, as well as all the others that came before, make super sense while answering my question on an architectural level. Design patterns would have solved my biggest broader problem at that time which I ended up never having. Clicking at the widespread "var that = this" hack as seen in @ cs_stackX's answer helped me at that point in time not only with this and the many other questions I had at that time, but also in lay down the fundamental knowledge required to understand yours and the second part of @ reed-spool's answer 7 years later. Thank you!